# Compila pero con warning y en el navegador no se ejecuta el archivo .js ¿Por qué y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, webpack

Tengo un problema, con mi aplicación en React y Node.js, estuve tratando de incorporar Server Side Rendering pero me dio infinitos problemas, había tomado un curso y quería practicar, pero me fue muy difícil siquiera hacerla compilar. Ahora la aplicación compila pero con 'warnings' y en el navegador no se ejecuta el javascript por un error "cannot read property '.css' of undefined". Cabe aclarar que estoy en el servidor de desarrollo [image: En el bash me muestra que compiló pero con errores]

[image: Aquí algunos warnings (porque son más)]

[image: El error que me muestra en el navegador al entrar en el servidor]

Aqui dejo mi package.json

```
{
  "name": "pronunciation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack-cli --config ./webpack.config.js --mode production --colors",
    "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.dev.config.js --mode development",
    "build:dll": "webpack --config ./webpack.dll.config.js --mode production",
    "server:dev": "nodemon src/server/index.js --exact babel-node",
    "server:prod": "node src/server/index.js --exact babel-node",
    "homepage": "https://imceler.github.io/pronunciation/dist",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.6.3",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "3.1.3",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "3.2.0",
    "css-mqpacker": "7.0.0",
    "cssnano": "4.1.10",
    "eslint": "6.5.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.16.0",
    "file-loader": "4.2.0",
    "gh-pages": "2.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.8.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "postcss-custom-media": "7.0.8",
    "postcss-import": "12.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "1.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "url-loader": "2.2.0",
    "webpack": "4.39.3",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.7",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/register": "^7.8.3",
    "asset-require-hook": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.22.0",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "gsap": "2.1.3",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "react": "16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "16.10.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.19",
    "react-redux": "7.1.1",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-config": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
    "redux": "4.0.4",
    "webpack": "^4.39.3",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Ahora dejo la configuración de webpack de producción que pienso puede tener algún error

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const TerserJSPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
// const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'hidden-source-map',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/server/index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), './src/server/public'),
    filename: 'assets/[name].[hash].js',
    publicPath: '/',
    chunkFilename: 'assets/[id].[chunkhash].js',
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: false,
    __filename: true,
    __dirname: true,
  },
  externals: ['ws'],
  target: 'node',
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserJSPlugin({})],
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'async',
      name: true,
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all',
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
          priority: 1,
          filename: 'assets/vendor.js',
          enforce: true,
          test(module, chunks) {
            const name = module.nameForCondition && module.nameForCondition();
            return chunks.some((chunks) => chunks.name !== 'vendor' && /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/.test(name));
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, '/src'), 'node_modules/'],
    descriptionFiles: ['package.json'],
    extensions: ['.jsx', '.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: {
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpg|png|gif|woff|eot|ttf|svg|mp4|webm$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            // limit: 10000,
            name: 'assets/[hash].[ext]',
              // outputPath: 'assets',
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        postcss: [
          autoprefixer(),
        ],
      },
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'assets/[name].[hash].css',
      chunkFilename: 'assets/[id].[hash].css',
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ['**/main.*'],
    }),
    new ManifestPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

Luego de toquetear algunas cosas en webpack me dio un nuevo error en el navegador que ahora es menos comprensible para mí.Lo que cambie fue que ahora en vez de url-loader utilizo file loader esto hace que todoso mis assets sean compilados en la carpeta 'public' cosa que antes no pasaba.

[image: El segundo error que me muestra despues de tocar algunas cosas]

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir las partes del código donde sospeches que pueda estar el error? Fíjate que te dice que no puede acceder a la propiedad .css, ¿tienes algún objeto en el que hayas accedido de forma parecida a: objeto.css y que objeto esté undefined? ¿Puede ser que tengas algún error de sintaxis cerca de la inclusión de un fichero css?

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que puede ser un fallo de configuración de webpack ya que cambie algunas cosas y el error también cambio, eso o babel. Revise el código pero las únicas partes donde entra a un objeto .css es en los imports de las hojas de estilos pero todo esta correcto. Subiré mis configuraciones de webpack

Comment: Buenas, te diría que el error proviene de aqui: `new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'assets/[name].[hash].css',
      chunkFilename: 'assets/[id].[hash].css',
    }),`
Es el único sitio que parece hacer referencia a un fichero .css, revisa que en tiempo de ejecución estén los archivos disponibles